# Drawing an image inside canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

this is my jsfidle : http://jsfiddle.net/2YDNq/

I can't figure out what i am doing wrong. i am trying to draw the first tiles of this image inside the canvas but nothing is happening .

```
function Character(x, y, speed, TilesPos, TilesRow) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.w = 25;
            this.h = 25;
            this.sp = speed;
            this.Pos = TilesPos;
            this.Row = TilesRow;
            this.MaxTiles = 11;
        }

        Character.prototype.draw = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(charImg, this.Pos * this.w, this.w * this.Row, this.w, this.h, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        };
        var character = new Character(cw / 2, (ch - 25), 1, 1, 1);
        function Draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
            if (charImg.complete){
                character.draw();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never setting the width and height properties of your canvas. The default size of 300x150. You're drawing your image outside of those dimensions so thats why you're not seeing it. If you use CSS to resize it, it only stretches the canvas to fit those dimensions distorting your image, but not changing the canvas coordinate system.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/2YDNq/4/)**

I added/changed these lines.

```
   var canvas = $('#My_Canvas')[0];
   canvas.width = 400;
   canvas.height = 400;
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Also as a heads up you don't need jQuery if you're just working with the canvas element, adds unneeded overhead.

Also for animations instead of using `setInterval` I highly recommend you checkout [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: but i am setting it's width and height from the html doing this : 
`<canvas id="My_Canvas" style="width:400px;height:400px;border:1px solid black"></canvas>`

Comment: @Sora I updated my answer. Setting canvas width and height via CSS only distorts the canvas, you have to set the width and height properties of the canvas element itself.

Comment: Also, be sure the image is loaded before you try to draw it: charImg.onload = function() {
               Draw();
           }
            charImg.src = "https://lh3.ggpht.com/-q0CJBWRLWUs/T_z2_c7TunI/AAAAAAAABPk/rS7fmE1P-B4/s320/megaman7.png";

Comment: @Sora you're welcome. If it answered your question an accepted answer would be appreciated.